# Setas utilizando apenas CSS

Tags: css, css3

Gostaria de saber, se é possível, efetuar a seguinte seta, utilizando apenas CSS:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Costumo efetuar outros tipos de setas, utilizando CSS, porém sempre que me debato com casos igual a este, onde a seta possui um fundo transparente, acabo utilizando imagens.

Comment: Pode usar o caracter `>` com `::after` já experimentou?

Comment: Complementando o Sergio acima: elemento::after { content: ">";}

Comment: Normalmente usam os icones como se fossem fontes.

Comment: Havia feito dessa forma, porém, a fonte fica muito diferente, e os designers aqui da empresa piram kkk

Comment: Usa ela como background entao. elemento::after { content:""; width: 15px; height: 15px; background: caminhodaimagem no-repeat center;}
Sabendo que a imagem deva ser salva com fundo transparente.

Comment: Sim sim, seria a forma que o amigo citou abaixo, queria ver como fazer sem imagem mesmo, mas obrigado mesmo assim! :D

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Usando CSS eu faria assim, estilizando do modo que quiser.

```css
.seta {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 3rem; /* Arrow size */
          box-shadow: 1px -1px 0 1px red inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px -2px red inset;
  border: solid transparent;
  border-width: 0 0 2rem 2rem;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.seta-direita { transform:rotate(225deg) }
```

```html
<div class="seta seta-direita"></div>
```

Comment: *Holy shit!* :o

Comment: +1 - ótima sacada. =)

Answer (score 6):

Tente isso:

```css
html, body {font-size: 14px}
button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0.1em solid #000;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0.75em 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
button:hover {cursor: pointer}
button:after {
    border-right: 0.1em solid #000;
    border-bottom: 0.1em solid #000;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1em;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 1em;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" role="button"> Ver mais projetos </button>
```